# Multiple focus selectors to dinamically show QuillJS toolbar, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, css-selectors, quill

I'm using Django's QuillJS version, and what I'm trying to do is display the toolbar of the selected text area only.
Using JS it kinda worked:

```
const parentDiv = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("django-quill-widget-container"));
const toolbar = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("ql-toolbar"));
const editor = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor"));

for (let i = 0; i < editor.length; i++) {
    toolbar[i].style.display = "none";
    parentDiv[i].style.borderTop = "1px solid #ccc";
    editor[i].addEventListener("focusin", function () {
      toolbar[i].style.display = "";
      parentDiv[i].style.borderTop = "";
    });
    editor[i].addEventListener("focusout", function () {
      toolbar[i].style.display = "none";
      parentDiv[i].style.borderTop = "1px solid #ccc";
    });
}
```

The problem is that clicking the toolbar to utilize its features also counts as focusout.

So yeah, it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Create a focusin listener function, create a focus out listener function and create a listener clear function. You call focusin listener function to create the listeners for a one time use only with memory of its whereabouts so when action is completed you run the clear function and now check for focusout till completed then cleared and restarted. You just need to sort how they reset. Close attempt however but another suggestion here cause the loop would be to do listen on the entire window/document not x amount of elements.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will try this right now

Comment: window.addEventListener("focusin", (event) => {if (event.target.id == "media") {}}, { passive: true, once: true }); If you did it this way, track all elements by ID if you have special treatment for them and know which state was toggled last, also allows you to skip that nasty loop if correctly setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a more simplistic approach:

```
const parentDiv = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("django-quill-widget-container"));
const toolbar = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("ql-toolbar"));
const editor = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor"));


function clearToolbar(index) {
  toolbar[index].style.display = "none";
  parentDiv[index].style.borderTop = "1px solid #ccc";
}

let editorArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

for (let i = 0; i < editor.length; i++) {
  toolbar[i].style.display = "none";
  parentDiv[i].style.borderTop = "1px solid #ccc";
  editor[i].addEventListener("focusin", function () {
    Array.prototype.except = function(val) {
      return this.filter(function(x) { return x !== val; });
    };

    parentDiv[i].style.borderTop = "";
    toolbar[i].style.display = "";
    editorArray.except(i).forEach(clearToolbar);
  });
}
```

It filters an array that contains the TextInputs indexes, excluding the index of the selected Text Field, and apply the styles I need.
Without the focusout listener the toolbar now works perfectly.